# Scope Passing arguments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

In the Rails Active Record model we use scopes, for scopes, we pass the arguments. But my doubt is when we pass the default value to the argument it shows the result from that value, when we pass value when executing it shows the newly passed values result, how the values are over written

This is the scope in the model

```
scope :ftr_post,->(start_date = Date.yesterday,end_date = Date.tomorrow) {where("created_at between ? and ?",start_date,end_date)}
```

When I run the following in console

```
Post.ftr_post
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (created_at between '2023-01-24' and '2023-01-26')
```

It return default arguments

When I run the following

```
Post.ftr_post("2023-01-11","2023-01-20").count
  Post Count (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE (created_at between '2023-01-11' and '2023-01-20')
```

it show the new passed arguments values

Please explain me in detail

Comment: You have written code for that only, what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written code for that and it is working fine.

```
scope :ftr_post,->(start_date = Date.yesterday,end_date = Date.tomorrow) {where("created_at between ? and ?",start_date,end_date)}
```

In the ruby, we use `PARAMETER = ANY_VALUE` in the method for defining default values.

```
Post.ftr_post
```

In the above first queries, you are not passing any argument hence it is taking default values `start_date` and `end_date` which are `Date.yesterday`  and `Date.tomorrow`.

```
Post.ftr_post("2023-01-11","2023-01-20").count
```

In the second query, you are explicitly passing the arguments hence method will take that values instead of default values. Therefore, it is taking `start_date` as `2023-01-11` and `end_date` as  `2023-01-20`.

Please read here if you want to know more about [parameter with default values in ruby](https://medium.com/@sologoubalex/parameters-with-default-values-in-ruby-74cd0e830681)